# SharePoint search special characters

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, search

I have a page in a pages library with a column containing 
`["cVRxqxdOHe"]`

If I perform a search for `cVRxqxdOHe`, the page returns in the results.

Using `["cVRxqxdOHe"]` as a search term returns no results. Do I need to escape the caracters? Using URL encoding doesn't work, e.g. `%5B%22cVRxqxdOHe%22%5D`

Comment: And the question is how do I search for all items containing `cVRxqxdOHe` in a site column?

Comment: No it's how to search specifically for `["cVRxqxdOHe"]`. It's pretty obvious if you read the question.

Comment: But this solved it? "f I perform a search for cVRxqxdOHe, the page returns in the results."

Comment: The search needs to be more specific, to find exactly `["cVRxqxdOHe"]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a value in a specific column, use

```
SiteColumnName:cVRxqxdOHe
```

If you have a site column (and not a list column) added to a list or library which contains the value cVRxqxdOHe, and a full crawl have been performed, the above search string will return all items containing cVRxqxdOHe in that site column.

[image]

Reference: [Exam Ref 70-339 Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-339-managing-microsoft-sharepoint-server-9781509302949)

This behavior is also valid for SharePoint 2013.